# Puppeteer querySelector returns null

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to scrap some data with puppeteer but for some sites querySelector returns null and I have no idea what is wrong. I found some answers about this issue in stackoverflow but none of them worked. Here is the code with an example link that does not work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.macys.com/shop/product/the-north-face-mens- 
    logo-half-dome-t-shirt?ID=2085687&CategoryID=30423&cm_kws=2085687');

    const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.price');
});

console.log(textContent); 

browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After taking a snapshot of the page, it turned out that my request gets blocked by a bot detection system. Here is the solution. We just need to pass some more data so it wont be detected as a bot. If it still not working, you can check out [this tutorial](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/).

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// This is where we'll put the code to get around the tests.
const preparePageForTests = async (page) => {

// Pass the User-Agent Test.
const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +
  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';
await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
}


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await preparePageForTests(page);

 // await page.setRequestInterception(true);
 await page.goto('websiteURL');

 const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
   return {document.querySelector('yourCSSselector').textContent,
 }
 });
  console.log(textContent);

  browser.close();
```

Comment: This gave me the idea to take a screenshot, which revealed to me that i was  actually working in the wrong tab

Comment: Thank you. I faced the same problem. 

Just to clarify how to make a screenshot with puppeteer for future readers, I did this:

  await page.screenshot({
    path: "./screenshot.jpg",
    type: "jpeg",
    fullPage: true
  });

Which saves a screenshot in the root folder of your project after running the script.

Answer (score 31):

Probably the elements are loaded asynchronously via javascript and are still not in the DOM when you're calling .evaluate().

Try to wait for the selector with puppeteer .waitForSelector function

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.macys.com/shop/product/the-north-face-mens- 
logo-half-dome-t-shirt?ID=2085687&CategoryID=30423&cm_kws=2085687');

await page.waitForSelector('.price');

const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
   return document.querySelector('.price');
});

console.log(textContent); 

browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought the problem was that the page wasn't fully loading, but after taking a snapshot of the page, it turned out that my request was getting blocked by a bot detection system. I'll post the solution.

Comment: Where is `document` defined?  It seems like it shouldn't exist in this context.