# Can't find any tags using NodeJS, puppeteer, and document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dom, puppeteer

I have a NodeJS Typescript project, and I am trying to get all the 'p' tags from a dynamically rendered website (not STATIC HTML but instead makes multiple requests to backend to get some data and render webpage). I am using typescript and have ["es6", "dom"] in my lib, and I have the following code (this is all my code in the project so far):

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const getLinks = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://webscraper.io/test-sites', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    const links = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('p'));
    console.log(links);
    await browser.close();
}
```

However, I keep getting `undefined` when I print `links`. I assume this is because the program can't find any 'p' tags. Why is this?

Note: the url provided is just an example. I have tried across multiple different sites and I still get undefined.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer querySelector returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663992/puppeteer-queryselector-returns-null)

Comment: You need to return serializable data from `evaluate`. DOM nodes aren't serializable. Either return element handles with `evaluateHandle` or pull out some property from these nodes like text content and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `page.evaluate` to get elements, use `waitForSelector`/`waitForXpath`/`$x`/`$$` instead (see Puppeteer doc to know the differences between them: https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pageselector-1):

```js
const links: ElementHandle[] = await mainPage.$$("p");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved an issue with a solution found [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1805) I wasn't able to find and click on an anchor tag with **page.evaluate**, **waitForFunction**, or **waitForSelector**. The solution was:

```
await page.focus('what-ever-the-selector-is')
await page.keyboard.type('\n');
```

this then clicked me into the next page